# Selenium sendkeys ctrl+5 is not working

Tags: selenium

I have a requirement wherein

- I need to invoke F12 developer tool in IE.
- Navigate to profiler tab.
- start profiler

I am using IE 9. In the below code, I am trying to navigate by entering <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. It is not working.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Keyboard;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class InvokeIEbrowser {

    @Test
    public void IEdriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
            "D:\\2015\\softwares\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.48.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        capabilities.setCapability("ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS", true);

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        /*
        Keyboard keyboard = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getKeyboard();
        keyboard.sendKeys(Keys.F12);
        */

        /*
        driver.get("http://mail.yahoo.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        */

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("String")).SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad5);
        //keyboard.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
        //getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.F5);

        Actions actionObject = new Actions(driver);
        actionObject.sendKeys(Keys.F12).perform();

        //actionObject.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD5).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();

        actionObject.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL.NUMPAD5).perform();
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `Keys.chord()` (more about it [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("String")).SendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.NUMPAD5 ));
```

or by using the `Action` class and the unicode representation:

```
 Actions action = new Actions(); 
  action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0035')).perform();
```

You can find more references about the unicode representation [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf).

Comment: Thank you let me try and get back here

Comment: I am getting this error : The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) org.openqa.selenium.Keys, org.openqa.selenium.Keys                             so i change it to below, but it did not worked.               driver.findElement(By.xpath("String")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"NUMPAD5" ));

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0035')).perform();

The above action is performed on browser not on developer tool window. The focus is always on the browser not on the developer tool.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's `,` instead of `+`. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to send the hotkey to the page?  Try an extension of driver...

```
public static void sendCtrl5(this IWebDriver Driver)
    {
        Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Click(); // make window active
        new Actions(Driver)
            .SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.NumberPad5)
            .Perform();
    }
```

Use: driver.sendCtrl5();

Comment: Thank you let me try and get back here

Comment: I am getting this error : The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) org.openqa.selenium.Keys, org.openqa.selenium